# Intercept a dynamic added form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normal form submission intercept can be found. But, my class is different. The form is dynamically added after calling a function. Then, the form submission cannot be captured.

**How to capture the form submission like this? Better to use Jquery but altering the dynamic added form attributes is acceptable.**

The following is the example.
Here is how I capture the form submission.

```
$(function() {
    $(".formClass").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var actionurl = e.currentTarget.action;
      alert(actionurl);
    });
});
```

Here is how forms are added after calling the function - eObj.getFormElement()

```
(function($){
    function(eObj) {
        var selector = "#abc";

        //Call the function to get the form elements
        eObj.getFormElement(langObj, function(err, x) {
            var elem = "<ul>";
            for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
                 var formId = elementId + "_sform_" + i;
                 elem = elem + "<li class='product_" + i + "'>" 
                 for (var key in x[i]) {
                      elem = elem + "<div class='price'>" + curMap[curKey] + x[i][key].price + "</div>";
                      elem = elem + "<div class='s'><form id='" + formId +"' class='formClass' method='post' action='" + x[i][key].url + "'>"
                           + "<input class='s_btn' type='submit' value='" + submitLabel + "'>"
                           + "</form></div>";
                 }
                 elem = elem + "</li>";
            }
            elem = elem + "</ul>";

        //Append the form to the div after we create the forms 
        $(selector).append(elem);
    }); 
}})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You can't set events for non-existing elements You need to set events for element existing.

In this case you can use `document` to get the event.

http://jsfiddle.net/h189o3xc/

here is a sample code.

```
$(document).on("submit",function(e){
    if($(e.target).hasClass("formClass")){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("you can catch the event!");
        //and do whatever you want.
    }
});
```

set a event for document and whenever any `submit` event happens, check whether it's your target form or not. then do whatever you want if it's your target form.

**EDITED**
as @charlietfl mentioned,You can use extra `on` function's parameter instead of `if` statement.

the code would be something like..

```
$(document).on("submit",".formClass",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("you can catch the event!");
      //and do whatever you want.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h189o3xc/2/

Comment: Missing target selector argument of `on`, no need for the `if` when you use target selector

Comment: thanks for the comment, updated the answer. this is why I do stackoverflow really appreciated

Comment: Looks like I cannot do whatever I want to. I want to submit the form after capturing the event. I end up with entering a loop.

Comment: then do not preventDefault just do whatever you want. after that, event bubbling up automatically and end up submitting.

Comment: I finally change the event capture. But, using the same idea. I capture the submit button click event and use that event to fetch the form. In this way, I avoid the loop.